# I am getting an issue while scheduling a run in AWS Device Farm from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using this command for executing from CLI -

```
aws devicefarm schedule-run --project-arn "project-arm value" --app-arn "app-arm value" --device-pool-arn "device-pool-arm value" --name "Automated_script" --test '{"type":"APPIUM_JAVA_TESTNG","testPackageArn":"testPackageArn value"}'
```

But getting this error

> An error occurred (ArgumentException) when calling the ScheduleRun operation: Missing or unprocessed resources.

Answer (score 2):

To Schedule a run, you need to do the following steps:

1. **[One time setup]** Call `aws devicefarm create-project` to create a project for all your tests
2. Call `aws devicefarm create-upload` for your application under test
3. Upload your application to the pre-signed URL returned by `create-upload`
4. Call `aws devicefarm create-upload` for your test scripts
5. Upload your test scripts to the pre-signed URL returned by `create-upload`
6. After your uploads have been processed by Device Farm, call `aws devicefarm schedule-run`

Normally when you see `"An error occurred (ArgumentException) when calling the ScheduleRun operation: Missing or unprocessed resources."`, it means you forgot step 3 or step 5. You can upload your application to the pre-signed URL using `curl`. You can check whether your upload has been successfully processed by calling `aws devicefarm get-upload`.

Here is an example blog post which uses the AWS CLI to schedule a run: [Get started with the AWS Device Farm CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/get-started-with-the-aws-device-farm-cli-and-calabash-part-1-creating-a-device-farm-run-for-android-calabash-test-scripts/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael Willingham. It helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Double-check all of your ARNs with a bash script:

```
PROJECT_ARN=<paste project ARN here>
APP_ARN=<paste app ARN here>
<define other ARNs here>

#Verify ARNs
aws devicefarm get-project --arn $PROJECT_ARN
aws devicefarm get-upload --arn $APP_ARN
aws devicefarm get-upload --arn $TEST_PACKAGE_ARN
aws devicefarm get-upload --arn $TEST_YAML_ARN
aws devicefarm get-device-pool --arn $DEVICE_POOL_ARN
aws devicefarm get-vpce-configuration --arn $VPCE_CONFIG_ARN
```

Our mistake was that one of our ARNs was for a test file which hadn't been uploaded, note the status initialized, not completed:

```
 ...
 "status": "INITIALIZED", 
            "category": "PRIVATE", 
            "contentType": "application/octet-stream", 
            "name": "googlePlayProdDebug-UITest-debug.apk", 
            ...
```

Another mistake was trying to use a device pool which was not a part of our project.  Device pools are specific to projects.

Try:
`aws devicefarm list-device-pools --arn <projectARN>`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case the "type" was wrong. My project is JNUIT

- Before: --test type=APPIUM_JAVA_TESTNG
- After: --test type=APPIUM_JAVA_JUNIT

aws devicefarm schedule-run --project-arn $PROJECT_ARN --app-arn $APP_UPLOAD_ARN --device-pool-arn $DEVICE_POOL_ARN --name customTestName --test type=**APPIUM_JAVA_JUNIT**,testPackageArn=$TESTS_UPLOAD_ARN

Answer (score 0):

My issue was invalid yaml file used for `testSpecArn`
You can check its validity with `yamllint`, this is how:

- install yamlling with homebrew: `brew install yamllint`
- go to directory where you yaml file is
- run `yamllint .`

If there are issues with your yaml file they will be described in terminal as errors, with red color.